# Presence of reaction module in bacteria but not in Eukaryotas (human)

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, database, data

From the [statistics](http://www.genome.jp/kegg/docs/module_statistics.html) page, I found that the [Module-M00008](http://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_module?M00008) is present only in bacteria and not Eukaryotes. Why so? I noticed that all the compounds necessary or the reaction are present in human body and also all the enzymes required for the reactions are present in human body too. Then why does that reaction not happen in humans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That module represents [Entner-Duodoroff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entner%E2%80%93Doudoroff_pathway) pathway, which is an alternative pathway to the Embden-Mayerhof-Parnas pathway of glycolysis.

Entner-Duordoff pathway exists only in prokaryotes.

Comment: so does this mean that the enzymes required for this particular pathway in bacteria are not present in Eukaryotas ?

Comment: @Rishika Precisely

Comment: so if these enzymes would have been present then which pathway would have had the more probability of occurring?

Comment: @Rishika That is a hypothetical question and the only answer would be that it would depend of different regulators of the glycolytic flux (in a manner how the fluxes through glycolysis and pentose phosphate pathway are regulated). Now don't ask me what those regulators could be because this question is as such hypothetical.

Comment: But according to the statistics , both the pathways of glycolysis are present in procaryotes, but the Entner-Duodoroff pathway is present only in procaryotes and not eucaryotes ... Any biological reason for this??

Comment: @Rishika, to add to this answer, there are three possibilities for discrepancy in coverage. 1) Limited information, i.e. even if the module exists in other species it has not been found (missing enzymes, proteins, etc.). 2) The information has not been added to the database (remember that this resource is manually curated). 3) It actually refers to different evolutionary paths. As WYSIWYG says, this is an alternative pathway. Either only the ancestors of prokaryotes found it or if other species found it, it did not increase fitness and was lost. You will find many more examples.

Comment: @Rishika And actually, reading the link to the Entner-Duodoroff pathway in wikipedia, it mentions that some prokaryotes use it as they lack enzymes critical for glycolysis. This suggests that even if "prokaryotes" have both glycolysis and this alternative according to the KEGG Module, maybe not the same prokaryote has both. At least it seems the case here.